# How to delete a non-empty directory using the Dir class?

Tags: ruby

```
Dir.delete("/usr/local/var/lib/trisul/CONTEXT0/meters/oper/SLICE.9stMxh")
```

causes this error:

> *Directory not empty - `/usr/local/var/lib/trisul/CONTEXT0/meters/oper/SLICE.9stMxh`*

How to delete a directory even when it still contains files?

Comment: 5 years and still this isn't possible in Ruby.

Answer (score 56):

Is not possible with `Dir` (except iterating through the directories yourself or using Dir.glob and deleting everything).

You should use

```
require 'fileutils'
FileUtils.rm_r "/usr/local/var/lib/trisul/CONTEXT0/meters/oper/SLICE.9stMxh"
```

Comment: Even FileUtils.rm_r path gives Directory not empty @ dir_s_rmdir error

Answer (score 8):

When you delete a directory with the `Dir.delete`, it will also search the subdirectories for files.

```
Dir.delete("/usr/local/var/lib/trisul/CONTEXT0/meters/oper/SLICE.9stMxh")
```

If the directory was not empty, it will raise `Directory not empty` error. For that ruby have `FiltUtils.rm_r` method which will delete the directory no matter what!

```
require 'fileutils'
FileUtils.rm_r "/usr/local/var/lib/trisul/CONTEXT0/meters/oper/SLICE.9stMxh"
```

Comment: Even FileUtils.rm_r path gives Directory not empty @ dir_s_rmdir  error.

Answer (score 0):

I use bash directly with the `system(*args)` command like this:

```
folder = "~/Downloads/remove/this/non/empty/folder"
system("rm -r #{folder}")
```

It is not really ruby specific but since bash is simpler in this case I use this frequently to cleanup temporary folders and files. The `rm` command just removes anything you give it and the `-r` flag tells it to remove files recursively in case the folder is not empty.